# Jersey / JAXB: Unmarshaling of empty json array results in a list with one item where all fields are set to null

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey

I have a really simple rest web service returning a list of questions. This code works as expected when the number of questions returned are greater than zero. But if the server returns an empty json array like [], JAXB creates a list with one question instance where all fields are set to null!

I'm new to both Jersey and JAXB so I don't know whether I haven't configured it correctly or whether this is a known problem. Any tips?

Client configuration:

```
 DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig config = new DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig();
 config.getProperties().put(DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig.PROPERTY_HANDLE_COOKIES, true);
 config.getClasses().add(JAXBContextResolver.class);
 //config.getClasses().add(JacksonJsonProvider.class); // <- Jackson causes other problems

 client = ApacheHttpClient.create(config);
```

JAXBContextResolver:

```
@Provider
 public final class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

  private final JAXBContext context;
  private final Set<Class> types;
  private final Class[] cTypes = { Question.class };

  public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
   this.types = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(cTypes));
   this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.natural().build(), cTypes);
  }

  @Override
  public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
   return (types.contains(objectType)) ? context : null;
  }

 }
```

Client code:

```
public List<Question> getQuestionsByGroupId(int id) {
    return digiRest.path("/questions/byGroupId/" + id).get(new GenericType<List<Question>>() {});
}
```

The Question class is just a simple pojo.

Comment: Similar problem here. Solved (but hacky): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197817

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly an answer to your question, but I choosed to use GSON on top of jersey, for my current projects. (and I try to avoid JAXB as much as possible), and I found it very easy and resilient.

You just have to declare

```
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
```

or

```
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
```

or both, and use the GSON marshaller/unmarshaller, and work with plain Strings. Very easy to debug, unittest too...

Answer (score 0):

Using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) may help.
See [org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html) and [org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize.Inclusion.html#NON_EMPTY)

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;

public class SampleContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>
{
        @Override
        public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type)
        {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            mapper.setSerializationConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig()
                .withSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
        }
}
```