# Transforming empty element into null when unmarshalling with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

A class is defined with the following JAXB annotation:

```
class Course {
@XmlElement (name = "book")
List<Book> requiredBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

When unmarshalling an XML document that contains this

```
<course>
  ...
  <book/>
</course>
```

I end up with a Book added to the list, with all of its attributes set to null.  I don't control the XML input.  How can I prevent this empty book from being added?  I tried intercepting in set..() or add..() methods, but turns out JAXB bypasses setters when dealing with collections.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution that *does* work.  Again, elegance was left behind.

There are two callbacks defined by JAXB: beforeUnmarshal and afterUnmarshal.  By implementing afterUnmarshal to clean up the list, I was able to achieve the desired result.

```
  class Course
  {
    @XmlElement (name = "book")
    List<Book> requiredBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();  
    ...
    void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller aUnmarshaller, Object aParent)
    {
        if (requiredBooks != null)
        {
            Iterator<Book> iterator = requiredBooks.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext())
            {
                Book book = iterator.next();
                if (StringUtils.isEmpty(book.getTitle()))
                {
                    // a book without title is considered invalid
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

While this works, by biggest issue with it is the absence of an interface for implementing afterUnmarshal.  It's looked up by JAXB using reflection, but I think it would've been convenient (and would reduce debugging/maintenance) if JAXB simply supplied interfaces and/or absract implementations.  As it is, what if the signature of afterUnmarshal changes in the future?  This code will just mysteriously stop working as it's supposed to.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Lousy solution but at least it works. No chance you found a better fix?

Answer (score 4):

In [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) we have the concept of a null policy.  This null policy gives you some flexibility on how to represent null.

You could modify your class to look like the following:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlMarshalNullRepresentation;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlNullPolicy;

@XmlRootElement
class Course {

    @XmlElement (name = "book")
    @XmlNullPolicy(
        nullRepresentationForXml = XmlMarshalNullRepresentation.EMPTY_NODE, 
        emptyNodeRepresentsNull=true)
    List<Book> requiredBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
}
```

This informs MOXy JAXB that for this property you wish to treat empty elements as null for this property.

For this XML:

```
<course>
    <book/>
    <book>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </book>
    <book/>
</course>
```

The *requiredBooks* property would unmarshal as: null, aBook, null.

There is currently a bug that is preventing this from working that we are addressing now.  You can track the progress on this issue here:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/330402

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that possibility for MOXy (another thread discussed it).  I can only wish it was available in JAXB by default.  It seems odd that such an option was left out.

Answer (score 2):

Well, <strike>I found one way to do it, although I don't find it super elegant.</strike>

**Edit:** Actually, the solution below **doesn't** work properly.  It actually causes no entries to be added to the list, regardless of them being an empty element or fully formed with data.

Maybe I've done it wrong, so any comments are welcome.

I created an adapter to handle the conversion and informed JAXB using an annotation:

```
class Course {
@XmlElement (name = "book")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BookListAdapter.class)
List<Book> requiredBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

and then defined my adapter:

```
static class BookListAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Book[], List<Book>>
{
    public Book[] marshal(List<Book> aBookList)
    {
        if (aBookList!= null)
        {
            return aBookList.toArray(new Book[aBookList.size()]);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<Book> unmarshal(Book[] aBookArray)
    {
        List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
        if (aBookArray != null)
        {
            for (Book book : aBookArray)
            {
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(book.getTitle()))
                {
                    bookList.add(book);
                }
            }
        }
        return bookList;
    }
}
```

<strike>It works as I want it to, but, as I said earlier, I'm not convinced of its elegance.</strike>
**Edit:** As described above, this doesn't work but probably due to some error on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
class Course {
@XmlElement (name="book", required=false)
List<Book> requiredBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks, but it didn't work.  I imagine that this directive tells JAXB not to consider it an error if the element is missing entirely, but it doesn't alter the behaviour when there's an occurrence of an empty tag.

Comment: @torngat: Have you tried `required` with `nillable`? I am blindly guessing, actually, because can't believe it doesn't have any build-in solution for this very basic usual reasonable requirement.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and no result.  My understanding at this point is that those extra instructions are used mainly for marshalling (i.e. generating) the XML.  The marshaller would then know that an element isn't required but, should it be null, it would be included like this:  <element xsd:nil="true"/>

Comment: @torngat: If that's the case, why not just shun JAXB, if possible, and use XStream or Simple XML Framework. Both are having this feature. And I am pretty sure you won't miss any. Or perhaps exploring XMLBeans, which is quite similar to JAXB, has this feature.

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar cludge:

```
public List<Photo> getPhotos() {
    removeUninitializedPhotos();
    return photos;
}

private void removeUninitializedPhotos() {
    List<Photo> photosToRemove = new ArrayList<Photo>();
    for (Photo photo : photos) {
        if (photo.getId() == null) {
            photosToRemove.add(photo);
        }
    }
    photos.removeAll(photosToRemove);
}
```

But I found it so horrible that I just ended up switching to [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem - I've need to handle an ArrayList containing interfaces. I've just created an adapter for interface (MyInterfaceAdapter) and annotated the List:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="myInterface")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=MyInterfaceAdapter.class)
List<MyInterface> list = new ArryList<MyInterface>;
```

My adapter looks like this:

```
public class MyInterfaceAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MyType, MyInterface> {

@Override
public Sensor unmarshal(MyType v) throws Exception {
    return (MyInterface) v;
}

@Override
public AbstractSensor marshal(MyInterface v) throws Exception {     
        if(v == null) //In the case of empty list
        {
         return null;
        } else
        { .....return new ... }
    }
}
```

After unmarshalling I've got an initialized ArrayList (even empty).

I think in the problem asked above one can add additional conditions and return null in the case of empty book. On the other hand I also dislike returning null.