# Jax-WS - To Remove Empty Tags from Request XML

Tags: xml, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, moxy

I'm trying to consume a web service exposed by a provider. The Provider has a strict checking at his end that the request xml should not contain tags which don't have values.

I'm using Jax-WS. If i don't set value in a particular object, it is being sent as empty tag and the tag is present. PFB the example illustrating my issue.

Client XML :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:host="http://host.testing.webservice.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <host:testingMathod>
         <arg0>
            <PInfo>
               <IAge>45</IAge>
               <strName>Danny</strName>
            </PInfo>
            <strCorrId>NAGSEK</strCorrId>
            <strIpAddress></strIpAddress>
         </arg0>
      </host:testingMathod>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In this, the value for IpAddress is not been given and hence the empty tag is been sent.

Hence kindly let us me know what needs to be done to remove the empty tags in request xml. Is Handlerchain is the only solution for the same?

Thanks,
Naveen.

Comment: Nobody knows a solution for this? Else it is so simple that nobody wants to reply? Please help me out..

Comment: I'm the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead and I've added an answer that should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11249220/383861

Answer (score 11):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

By default MOXy like other JAXB implementations will not marshal an element for null values:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html

**POSSIBLE PROBLEM**

I believe the `strIpAddress` property is not null, but contains a value of empty String (""). This would cause the empty element to be written out.

***Root***

```
package forum11215485;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    String nullValue;
    String emptyStringValue;
    String stringValue;

}
```

***Demo***

```
package forum11215485;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.nullValue = null;
        root.emptyStringValue = "";
        root.stringValue = "Hello World";

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

***Output***

Note how there is no element marshalled out for the `nullValue` field, and the `emptyStringValue` field is marshalled as an empty element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <emptyStringValue></emptyStringValue>
   <stringValue>Hello World</stringValue>
</root>
```

**SOLUTION #1 - Ensure the property is set to null and not ""**

**SOLUTION #2 - Write an XmlAdapter that converts "" to null**

An `XmlAdapter` is a JAXB mechanism that allows an object to be marshalled as another object.

***StringAdapter***

The following `XmlAdapter` will marshal empty strings as null.  This will cause them not to appear in the XML representation.

```
package forum11215485;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class StringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        if(null == v || v.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return v;
    }

}
```

***package-info***

The `XmlAdapter` is hooked in using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation.  Below is an example of hooking it in at the package level so that it applies to a fields/properties of type String within the package.  For more information see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-package-level-xmladapters.html

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=StringAdapter.class, type=String.class)
package forum11215485;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.*;
```

***Output***

Now the output from running the demo code is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <stringValue>Hello World</stringValue>
</root>
```

Comment: +1 because you are a hard worker! And also because I agree the if there is some empty string, an adapter is the way to go to remove it.

Comment: Setting those property values to null is a clean way to exclude them if they are not set to a value during processing, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of the XML Serializer that you are using (If you did not do something special it should be JAXB).

The "null policy" of the serializer should be configurable, but I think is not possible with JAXB. If you use [MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) you can use `XmlMarshalNullRepresentation.ABSENT_NODE` to do not write the node if it is null. The implementation should be something like this:

```
class MyClass {

    // ... here are your other attributes

    @XmlElement (name = "strIpAddress")
    @XmlNullPolicy(nullRepresentationForXml = XmlMarshalNullRepresentation.ABSENT_NODE)
    String strIpAddress = null;

}
```

*PS: Maybe you need to define also the `emptyNodeRepresentsNull` param of the `@XmlNullPolicy`.*

For more information about this subject, please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181120/transforming-empty-element-into-null-when-unmarshalling-with-jaxb)

Comment: +1 for `@XmlNullPolicy`.  However, I believe the issue is related to the `strIpAddress` containing an empty string.  I have added an answer demonstrating how this could be solved with an `XmlAdapter`:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11249220/383861

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, when serializing a class where I couldn't use annotations (`LogRecord`):

```
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(LogRecord.class);
            JAXBElement<LogRecord> je = new JAXBElement<>(new QName("log"), LogRecord.class, record);
            Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.setAdapter(new XmlAdapter<String,String>() {
                @Override
                public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {
                    if(null == v || v.length() == 0) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    return v;
                }
                @Override
                public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
                    return v;
                }
            });
            ByteArrayOutputStream xml = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            marshaller.marshal(je, xml);
```