# How to remove null tags in xml request in spring webservice?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

I have come across a problem in which empty or null tag (complex element) is passed from xml it is coming as a `not null` object in the java code.

For example :

Suppose my jaxb generated class name is `Employee` having two simple elements id and name.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;  
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;  

@XmlRootElement  
public class Employee {  
    private int id;  
    private String name;  

@XmlElement  
public int getId() {  
    return id;  
}  
public void setId(int id) {  
    this.id = id;  
}  
@XmlElement  
public String getName() {  
    return name;  
}  
public void setName(String name) {  
    this.name = name;  
}  
}
```

Now if i pass `<Employee></Employee>` from xml request,the object employee is not coming as null.I want this employee in the object as null to avoid certain logic which is inside the if condition:

```
if(employee!=null)
```

To generate the java classes from xsd, xjc tool is used (ant script).So the solutions on stackoverflow is not applicable in my scenario:-
[Jax-WS - To Remove Empty Tags from Request XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215485/jax-ws-to-remove-empty-tags-from-request-xml#)

SOLUTION #1 - Ensure the property is set to null and not ""

SOLUTION #2 - Write an XmlAdapter that converts "" to null

Please help me making the blank/empty tag of xml string to null object.Is there any ant xjc property which can be used to achieve this?

Comment: in your example, Employee is a valid xml element and it should not be null. The xml element value is empty "".  You can add an if statement if the  xml value length is == 0 then return null.

Comment: Employee class don't have any  length method.How to use length?

Comment: please show the source code for the class Employee, add it to your question

Comment: look at this tutorial and see if you can apply the methods to your question, http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxb-representing-null-and-empty.html