# How can I get the JAXB to generate empty tags for non-string elements?

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, wsimport, jaxws-maven-plugin

**Edit: I have re-formatted the question to hopefully make my intentions clearer.**

I'm trying to map the java objects to XML using JAXB marshaller to create a soap request for a vendor SOAP service.
I have few elements which need to present in the request even if they are empty or null.
I use `jaxws-maven-plugin` plugin with `wsimport` goal in my pom.xml to generate sources from the WSDL files.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.helger.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <wsdlFiles>
                <wsdlFile>${project.basedir}/src/wsdl/sample/SomeSoapService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
            </wsdlFiles>
        </configuration>
        <id>wsimport-generate-cbs</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    </execution>
</executions>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<configuration>
    <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxws-wsimport</sourceDestDir>
    <xnocompile>true</xnocompile>
    <xadditionalHeaders>true</xadditionalHeaders>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <extension>true</extension>
</configuration>
```

I've read and understood from here [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215485/jax-ws-to-remove-empty-tags-from-request-xml ] that for the elements with `xs:string` type, an empty tag can be generated by setting an empty string `""` as it's value. But it can't be done on the elements with types such as `xs:dateTime, xs:boolean, xs:integer` which will produce `XMLGregorianCalendar, BigInteger, Boolean` objects respectively. If I set their value as null, the elements will not be generated in marshaling process. Like others have pointed out, it can be achieved by adding `nillable=true` to the `@XmlElement` but that will require changing to the generated source which will be overwritten on the next build unless I remove the plugin from maven after the first build.

My current workaround is I changed the types of those particular elements that need to present in the request to `xs:string` in the WSDL files and passed the empty string to their corresponding java object fields.

My question is, is it possible to make changes in the WSDL side that will trigger jaxws:wsimport to add `nillable=true` in the generated `@XmlElement` fields? The reason I prefer to change the WSDL files instead of generated sources is that

1. I already have some changes in WSDL files so that all of the changes can be in one place, easier to document.
2. I would like to avoid changing the generated sources so that I can keep them out of Git repo and also prevent being overwritten on each build.

Following is the simplified version of the code.

First I have this generated java class for the complexType Currency.

```
// Generated    
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "currency", propOrder = {
    "crossCurrency",
    "amount"
})
public class Currency {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Boolean crossCurrency;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected BigDecimal amount;
}
```

And I set the fields as null because they don't exist.

```
requestInputRq.setCurrency(new Currency());
requestInputRa.setOtherField("Some value");
```

That will generate <typ:Currency /> but I need it to be generated like below.

```
<typ:Currency>
    <typ:crossCurrency/>
    <typ:amount/>
</typ:Currency>
```

Comment: set `crossCurrency` and `amount` to null, instead.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca ```new Currency()``` has already initialized them as null isn't it? I have just tried setting them null to be sure but tags are still not getting generated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Represent null value as empty element in xml jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366054/represent-null-value-as-empty-element-in-xml-jaxb)

Comment: @Lakshan Yes it does but I'd like to avoid making changes to the generated source files if possible because they will be overwritten in the next import. My current workaround is I changed the types of those mandatory fields in WSDL to xs:string and passed the empty string to trigger empty tags. This approach has costed me many number format validations but looks like it's the only way if I don't want to mess with the generated sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `nillable` attribute with `@XmlElement` and set it value to `true`

Currency.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "currency", propOrder = {
    "isoCurrencyCode",
    "amount"
})
public class Currency {

    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable=true)
    protected Boolean crossCurrency;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable=true)
    protected BigDecimal amount;
}
```

output

```
<typ:Currency>
    <typ:crossCurrency xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <typ:amount xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</typ:Currency>
```

WSDL

add the `nillable` attribute and set it value to `true` in every requested element as following example,

```
<xsd:element name="Currency" nillable="true" ... />
```

Comment: Hi Lakshan, thanks for your answer. In my case the source codes are generated from the wsdl so I'd like to avoid making changes to the generated sources if possible. Do you know if there's a way to make changes to WSDL instead so that ```nillable``` is added to @XmlElement when sources are being generated?

Comment: @MinNaingOo please refer above modified answer

Comment: @MinNaingOo if it works for you, please accept the answer :)

Comment: The last part is exactly what's I'm looking for. Thank you @Lakshan !